# Autodesk Forge Model derivative API - resumable upload in python

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am trying to implement resumable upload in Python for a file size 765759548 (765MB) bytes. I wrote a test code to upload first 5MB as follows:

```
fileHandle=open(FilePath,"rb")
payload = fileHandle.read(5*1024*1024)
sessionId = uuid.uuid4().hex
headers = { 'Authorization': GetToken(), 'Content-Type': 'application/stream', 'Content-Length': os.path.getsize(FilePath), 'Content-Range': 'bytes 0-5242879', 'Session-Id':sessionId }
conn.request("PUT", "/oss/v2/buckets/"+bucketKey+"/objects/"+FileName+"/resumable", payload, headers)
conn.getresponse()
```

But I get a null response from this piece of code. Would anyone please advice as what's going wrong here. Btw, this question is a continuation of the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70066883/autodesk-forge-model-derivative-api-504-gateway-timeout-status-and-no-objectid)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a Python sample for this I'm afraid but just judging from the code snippet:

- make sure that the value of the `Authorization` header actually has the form of `Bearer <token>` (I'm not sure what your `GetToken()` function returns)
- try adding the total size to the `Content-Range` header, e.g., `bytes 0-5242879/765759548`

And finally, please note that there's a very recent announcement about the Data Management service moving to a more efficient, "direct-to-s3" upload method: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/data-management-oss-object-storage-service-migrating-direct-s3-approach. With this approach, you would simply generate one or more S3 URLs, upload chunks of your file to these URLs, and in the end you would just make a final HTTP request to combine all these chunks into a file.

Comment: Thank you @Petr. `GetToken()` returns `Bearer<token>` and as you pointed out, there was an issue with the `Content-Range` and also `Content-Length`. I fixed it earlier and also developed the code to iterate through the whole file. Attaching the snippet in the Answer section, if it might help anyone!

Comment: Thanks for notifying the migration, shall check it out.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet worked for me:

```
with open(filename,"rb") as fr:
    readlimit = 5 * 1024 * 1024 
    n_splits = filesize//readlimit
    for i in range(n_splits + 1):
      spiltteddata = fr.read(readlimit)
      start = i * readlimit
      end = min(filesize, (i + 1) * readlimit) - 1
      length = end - start + 1
      #session_id = 
      payload = spiltteddata
      headers = {
        'Authorization': GetToken(),
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Length': str(length),
        'Content-Range': "bytes " + str(start) + "-" + str(end) + "/" + str(filesize), #f"bytes 0-{str(readlimit-1)}/{str(filesize)}",
        #'Connection':'close',
        'Session-Id': str(session_id)
      }
...
```